# Android, takes one second to get String from Sharedpreferences

Tags: android

I have following simple test where I try to fetch data from Sharedpreferences:

```
  long begin =  System.currentTimeMillis();
  long end = 0;
  Log.d(TAG, "getSharePreferences: " + begin+"");               

   SharedPreferences settings = cordova.getActivity().getSharedPreferences(preferenceLib, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

   end = System.currentTimeMillis(); Log.d(TAG, "getSharePreferences end 2: " + (end - begin));

  String returnValue = settings.getString(preferenceName, ""); // <- took 1 sec !!!!

  end = System.currentTimeMillis(); Log.d(TAG, "getSharePreferences end 3: " + (end - begin));
```

And results:

```
06-29 23:31:41.269: D/MeeterCalendar(21327): getSharePreferences end 2: 4
06-29 23:31:42.300: D/MeeterCalendar(21327): getSharePreferences end 3: 1031
```

Why to fetch String from `SharePreferences` takes about 700-1000 milliseconds?

The string is simple: `"true"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SharedPreferences` are stored in XML files on internal storage. Your call to `getPreferences()` will trigger a background thread to load and parse that XML file, but that work will not be complete by the time your `getString()` call occurs on the next line. You will wind up blocking waiting for the disk I/O and XML parsing to complete.

Comment: So as I understand it might happen if device is busy (disk I/O), right? Or during that period some other tasks use I/O hard

Comment: @fessy: Particularly on Android 1.x/2.x devices, you can get "caught up" by other apps doing disk I/O. Even on newer devices, on-board flash is a bit of a bottleneck, just because it's cheap and slow. It's also just a one-time price per process -- until your process is terminated, the preferences are cached.